# Can not find an object dynamically from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, google-api-nodejs-client

I have to get the client_id from an api call which would be available in body.

```
const oauthClients = [
  { "0ADAA2B8": "96eb8c0fbfb31ac43288" },
  { P3CKTGC7: "FKC78N6Plm1Vwjk8KItS" },
];

const client_id = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body.client_id));
const filtered_value = oauthClients.find((ele) => {
  return (ele.client_id = client_id);
});
console.log(filtered_value);
```

I have tried like return `${ele}`+`.`+`${req.body.client_id}

Anyone please help..!

Comment: Please use strict equality operator `===`. `=` is assignment operator. `oauthClients.find(ele => { return ele.client_id == client_id })`

Comment: can you please give more clarity on question like what is client id and expected result

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the strict equality operator instead

```
const filtered_value = oauthClients.find((ele) => {
  return ele.client_id === client_id;
});
```

Also `oauthClients` us an object so you can't really traverse it using `.find` and access `ele.client_id`, you will need to somehow take the object values and traverse them in an array like fashion

e.g. using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) :

```
const filtered_value = Object.keys(oauthClients).find((key) => {
  return oauthClients[key] === client_id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What makes this a bit hard is that your original data isn't really well structured:

Given this:

```
const oauthClients = [
  { "0ADAA2B8": "96eb8c0fbfb31ac43288" },
  { P3CKTGC7: "FKC78N6Plm1Vwjk8KItS" },
];
```

There's no "client_id" field - the client ID is the field name, so its hard to parse. In Javascript, to get generic access to the keys and values of a dictionary, you use the Object.keys() and Object.values() functions.

I think you're looking to get the token given the client ID, so something like this:

```
/**
 * Returns the token for the given client ID or undefined if it isn't found
 */
function findToken(clientId: string) {
   const foundElement = oauthClients.find(e => Object.keys(e)[0] === clientId)
   return foundElement 
     ? Object.values(foundElement)[0]
     : undefined
}
```